# How to Set Some of Entity Properties in Repository in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository

I have a DB that all of its entities have some log fields for Create/Modify/Delete and I have to take Current User Id in all of my CRUD Actions and set these fields for security purpose ....

this is an example of my Entities :

```
 //log properties
    public byte RecordStatus { get; set; }
    public string RecordStatusDescription { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string CreatorIPAddress { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string ModifierIPAddress { get; set; }
    public string RemovedBy { get; set; }
    public string RemovedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string RemoverIPAddress { get; set; }
    public bool IsRemoved { get; set; }
```

I'm using Repository and I want to add something like this to my IRepository interface :

```
public interface IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class 
{
    void Createdby(string UserId , string userIP);
    void ModifiedBy(string UserId ,  string userIP);
    void RemovedBy(string UserID , string userIP);
}
```

so how can I implement this in my Repository and then use it in my actions !?

I can set this fields in traditional way but I want to have more cleaner Actions ...

Comment: should I just define these in all of my [Entity]Repository !? I just don't want to copy past these methods in more than 20 [Entity]Repository !!

Comment: I knew that Repository is for separate direct interact with DB  but !? do you suggest that I should define separate class for these operation and define these method in there !?  or just use traditional way of setting properties in action !? what approach you would choose to solve this problem !?

Comment: checkout the answer, if you have any problem tell me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so you have to make a clear IRepository and make it as simple as possible like this(since you want this Generic):

**IRepository**:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Delete(int id);
    T GetById(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    void Update(T entity);
    void save();
}
```

And Create *One* Generic Repository like below:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : EntityBase
{

    internal MyDbContext context;
    internal DbSet<T> dbSet;
    public Repository()
    {

        context = new MyDbContext();
        this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();

    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        dbSet.Remove(dbSet.Find(id));
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
       return dbSet.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entity);
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Good thing about EntityBase is since all of your properties have an id, you can easily go like this:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

And then implement this to your **Models** :

```
public class Example : EntityBase
{

public byte RecordStatus { get; set; }
public string RecordStatusDescription { get; set; }
public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
public string CreatorIPAddress { get; set; }
public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
public DateTime ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
public string ModifierIPAddress { get; set; }
public string RemovedBy { get; set; }
public string RemovedDateTime { get; set; }
public string RemoverIPAddress { get; set; }
public bool IsRemoved { get; set; }

}
```

Advantage of using this simple Repository is you can easily do anything with it e.g. :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    Repository<Example> _repository = new Repository<Example>();


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        vm.Example = _repository.GetAll()
            .Where(x => x.RecordStatusDescription == "1").ToList(); 
        return View("index",vm);
    }
}
```

Comment: @RezaPouya glad to help =)

Comment: @RezaPouya you're welcome! it is the best practice btw :)